# Add object to dictionary based on key in Python 2

Tags: python

I'm trying to add an object/dictionary to my already existing dictionary based on key, but the already existing object is being overwritten.

What I am trying to achieve:

```
'CXR100': {'MeSH': {u'major': [u'normal'], u'minor': []}, {u'major': [u'normal'], u'minor': []}}
```

What I am getting:

```
'CXR100': {'MeSH': {u'major': [u'normal'], u'minor': []}}
```

My code:

```
data = dict()
for record in records['list']:
    if data.get(record['uid']):
        data[record['uid']]['MeSH'].update(record['MeSH'])
        # have tried: data[record['uid']]['MeSH'] += {'MeSH': record['MeSH']}
    else:
        data[record['uid']] = {'MeSH': record['MeSH']}

print(data)
```

I have been programming PHP/Laravel for the past two years and have totally lost my feeling for Python. I hope someone can give me directions on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What you want, is not a valid Python data structure. There is only one key, but presumably two values.

Comment: @schwobaseggl that explains a lot. What would i be able to do to achieve the same kind of data structure?

Comment: Do you want a single key and as value a list of dicts?

Comment: The 'MeSH' value should be a list of dictionaries rather than a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
for record in records['list']:
    if data.get(record['uid']):
        # ... and append to it later 
        data[record['uid']]['MeSH'].append(record['MeSH'])
    else:
        # make it a list initially ...
        data[record['uid']] = {'MeSH': [record['MeSH']]}
```

Or you can use `setdefault` to put in one line:

```
for record in records['list']:
    data.setdefault(record['uid'], {'MeSH': []})['MeSH'].append(record['MeSH'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just wrote the same code lol. It became clear to me when you pointed out that the data structure is off. Will accept when I can (: Have a great day!